# How to open Google Meet link through Gmail account in Ionic Capacitor

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

How to open Google Meet link as opened by Slack.

With my below code it is opening google PlayStore and asking us to download meet which i want to avoid.

Here is what I'm doing

```
   import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
   import { Browser } from '@capacitor/browser';


  async openMeetLink(){
    
    if(Capacitor.isNative){
            await Browser.open({ url: `https://meet.google.com/jhc-peu5-im&d?authuser=1&hl=en` 
        });
    }

}

openMeetLink();
```

How to open Meet link like Slack unlike my second gif which opens `Play Store`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the Google Meet link in a way similar to how Slack handles it, you can use the Capacitor InAppBrowser plugin to display the content inside your app rather than opening an external browser or the Play Store.

First, make sure you have the InAppBrowser plugin installed:

```
npm install @capacitor/in-app-browser
```

Then, modify your code as follows:

```
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@capacitor/in-app-browser';

async function openMeetLink() {
    if (Capacitor.isNative) {
        const meetLink = 'https://meet.google.com/jhc-peu5-im&d?authuser=1&hl=en';

        try {
            await InAppBrowser.create({ url: meetLink, presentationStyle: 'popover' });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error opening Meet link:', error);
            // Handle error as needed
        }
    }
}

openMeetLink();
```

In this code, `the InAppBrowser.create` method is used to open the Google Meet link. The presentationStyle: `'popover'` option specifies that the in-app browser should be displayed as a popover, which is a common way to show content within the app.

Make sure to check the Capacitor InAppBrowser plugin documentation for any additional configuration options or updates.

Comment: Your solution is interesting, but doesn't implement exactly the same behavior shown in the first GIF. Indeed, we can clearly see in that GIF that Google Meet was not open by the in-app browser, but the actual Google Meet app got opened.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** installing Google Meet on the phone (or whatever device used in the second GIF) will probably solve your problem.

**Explanation:** It looks like Google Meet is not installed on the device shown in the second GIF. Indeed, Google Play shows the button "Install" only when the displayed app is not installed.

[image: From second GIF - Google Meet not installed]

If Google Meet was already installed, Google Play would display "Uninstall" and "Open" buttons instead (screenshot below is in French, but it works the same in English).

[image: Uninstall and Open buttons when Google Meet is installed]

Therefore, installing Google Meet on that device will probably solve your problem.